# Haskell wrap function implementation

Tags: list, haskell

I have a problem with the implementation of this function:

#### TYPE SIGNATURE

```
wrap :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
```

#### PURPOSE

Insert `x` at every `n`th position in the list `xs`.

#### EXAMPLES

```
wrap 1 '+' "a" : "+a+"

wrap 2 '+' "a" : "+a"

wrap 2 '+' "abcd" : "+ab+cd+"
```

#### DEFINITION

```
wrap _ _ [] = []
wrap n x xs = insertAfter 0 xs
        where insertAfter = undefined
```

How can one implement this, I just can not figure it out. 
EDIT:

Full question:
Implement the function wrap, which generates a list that starts with wrap’s second argument (x), followed by as many entries from wrap’s third argument (xs) as dictated by wrap’s ﬁrst argument (n). Repeat until the third argument is empty. In the resulting list, every nth element should be equal to x. Insert an x in the end if the length of xs is evenly divisible by n.
Hint: Implement the function wrap in terms of the function insertAfter, which takes a number m and a listofelements xs, which decreases m as elements are removed from xs, and inserts x whenever m reaches 0.

I almost got it:

```
 wrap _ _ [] = []
 wrap n x xs = insertAfter 0 xs
   where insertAfter 0 xs = x : insertAfter n xs
         insertAfter _ [] = undefined
         insertAfter n xs = take n xs ++ (wrap n x (drop n xs))
```

but using the example: wrap 2 '+' "abcd" : wrap 2 '+' "abcd" : "+ab+cd+"
I get "+ab+cd" so theres a '+' missing.

Comment: Hint: use `mod`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, Hint 2: don't use `mod`. `mod` is relatively slow, so it's usually better to avoid it when you can. It's completely unnecessary in this case.

Comment: @dfeuer: well I would not violate Knuth's optimization principle: "*premature optimization is the root of all evil*" :) As with many algorithms that are designed, once an inefficient algorithm is designed, then optimizing is typically more straightforward.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, that's certainly a valid point in general, but in this particular case the alternative is just as simple, so there's no reason to take the detour.

Comment: So, we're just assuming that `wrap n x ys` is suppose to insert `x` into `ys` after every `n` characters? This question is woefully incomplete. (The edit history is quite long, so I'm hesitant to simply rollback the last edit that appears to have destroyed the question.)

Answer (score 2):

I've taken the liberty of changing the argument you pass to `insertAfter`. It's very often a bit more convenient to count *down* than to count *up*, and that's true here as well.

```
wrap :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
wrap _ _ [] = []
wrap n delim = insertAfter n
  where
     -- We've reached zero. So we insert the delimiter and
     -- reset the counter to n.
     insertAfter 0 xs = delim : insertAfter n xs
     -- All done
     insertAfter _ [] = ???
     -- Still some work to do
     insertAfter k (y : ys) = ???
```

An aside: what you called a "contract" is what we call a *type signature*. An actual *contract* will generally give a lot more detail about what is expected of the arguments and what is guaranteed of the result. For example, the contract here would specify that the first argument to `wrap` must be positive, and would give an explanation of what the function does.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I am not supposed to change the given code.

Comment: @DavisR5, read the problem statement again. You got it backwards.

Answer (score 1):

You may do as follows

```
wrap :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
wrap _ _ [] = []
wrap n c cs | n == length cs = c:cs++[c]
            | otherwise      = c:x ++ wrap n c y
              where (x,y) = splitAt n cs
```

`n == length cs` condition is required because both `splitAt 2..n "a"` and `splitAt 1 "a"` give `("a","")`. Also I assume `n >= 1` always.